# Android - How to transfer images on restful web services as json

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I have a model like;

```
public class Employee{
      String name;
      int age;
      String designation;
      double salary;
      ...........
```

and there will be another field; **employee's photo**

here is my question; how can I transfer this **employee** object or **employee list** object with restful web service as json object. I can convert my images(employee's photo) to String but is this best way to transfer image files.Could anyone give me an example about transfering image files in java models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON isn't built to stream raw data such as images. The best practice to do what you need is to supply a link to the image in the json field (a simple URL) and then download that image separately. The image itself can be stored raw "as is".